# Change HTML Button Based On Cookie Existance

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, conditional-statements

I want to edit an html button that will tell the user if they have read the page that the button is on. The button is at the bottom of the page, and starts off being red. After the user presses the button, a cookie is generated and the changeButton() function checks to see if the cookie has been created, and then changes the button to green. Even after the user closes and reopens the browser, the button should stay green until the cookie has been deleted.

My browser just shows the button as being green on page loadup, before I even hit the button. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeButton()
    {

        var name = 'user_read_the_page' + '=';
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
        {
            var c = ca[i];

            while(c.charAt(0)==' ')
            {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }

            if(c.indexOf(name) != -1)
            {
                var output = c.substring(name.length,c.length);
            }
        }       

        document.getElementById("test").innerText = output;

        if(output == 1)
        {
            cookie_exists = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cookie_exists = 0;
        }           

        if(cookie_exists == 1)
        {
            document.getElementById("read_button").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            document.getElementById("read_button").style.color = "white";
            document.getElementById("read_button").style.fontWeight = "bold";
            document.getElementById("read_button").innerText = "\u2714 You Have Read This Page";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("read_button").style.backgroundColor = "red";
            document.getElementById("read_button").style.color = "white";
            document.getElementById("read_button").style.fontWeight = "bold";
            document.getElementById("read_button").innerText = "\u2718 Please Read This Page";              
        }

        return "";
    }
</script>
</head>
```

...

```
<button id="read_button" onclick="createCookie('user_read_the_page', 30)"></button>

    <script language="javascript">

        function createCookie(name, days)
        {
            var expire = new Date ();
            expire.setTime (expire.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * days); 
            document.cookie = name + "=1; expires=" + expire.toGMTString();
            changeButton();
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Where is the code to initialize your button? There are only function declarations here... so, for me, the button does not appear green at page startup...

Comment: Its at the top of the second code window. The text and color get added when the "output" variable satisfies one of the if-than conditions.

Comment: Ok, at the fist time that the button is clicked, it gets green... Did you see that you are always setting the cookie to 1 (in the createCookie function) before reading it (in the changeButton function)?

Comment: Yes. Essentially, this is how everything should work. The button should be red upon first visit to the page. And then, a user comes along, reads the information on the page, and then clicks the button, which then adds a cookie to their computer, with a value of 1 in it. When they revisit the site, the code will automatically see the 1 in the cookie, and automatically light back up to green, letting the user know they already read this information. If the user never clicks the button, the button will always be red when they visit the site.

Comment: I think the error is that you have to remove the cookie to see the red case... Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rosberglinhares/7278m2o8/)